# How to retrieve reportProgress of multiple observables grouped in a forkJoin?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular project, I have a form for uploading several files (each could be large and I can't do only one POST with all files due to server POST limit size).

It would be nice if I could have a Material determinate progress-bar for each processus to show the progression.

```
let tabObservable:Array<Observable<any>> = [];

tabObservable.push( this.rfs.myPost('receive.php', formData1, {reportProgress : true, observe: "events"}) );
tabObservable.push( this.rfs.myPost('receive.php', formData2, {reportProgress : true, observe: "events"}) );
tabObservable.push( this.rfs.myPost('receive.php', formData3, {reportProgress : true, observe: "events"}) );
....

uploadAll = forkJoin( tabObservable );
upload().subscribe( 
    (event)=>{ 
          // contains httpReponses at the end of the forkJoin but nothing about progression...
    }, 
    (err)=>{ }
);
```

Is it possible ? Do I have to catch the "events" of each observable ?

Comment: did my fix worked for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the observables by adding a pipe, like this:

```
forkJoin(tabObservable.map(o => o.pipe(tap(() => this.count++))))
    .subscribe();
```

The tap function can be a custom function to update the progress bar 
Well, the count goes for a very bumpy ride, but it's one solution

See [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yqqcbw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you, it works but indeed it is a bumpy ride, and so it seems to be unsuitable for the progress bar (percentage). I'm searching more precisely thanks to your idea

Answer (score 2):

```js
const requests = [
  this.rfs.myPost('receive.php', formData1, {reportProgress : true, observe: "events"}),
  this.rfs.myPost('receive.php', formData2, {reportProgress : true, observe: "events"}),
  this.rfs.myPost('receive.php', formData3, {reportProgress : true, observe: "events"})
];

const uploadProgress$ = new ReplaySubject<HttpProgressEvent>();
const uploadComplete$ = new ReplaySubject<any[]>();

forkJoin(
  requests.map(req => {
    return req.pipe(
      tap(e => {
        if (e.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
           // you can check progress
          uploadProgress$.next(e as HttpProgressEvent);
        }
      })
    );
  })
).subscribe((responses: HttpResponse<any>[]) => {
  uploadComplete$.next(responses);
  uploadProgress$.complete();
  uploadComplete$.complete();
});

return [uploadProgress$, uploadComplete$];
```